# Insert Page in html design

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

i have designed one website with 20 pages and the menu and header have the css design my problem is if i change the menu content then i have to change all the page so how to make the separate page for the header.

I have tried   and include page method but not work please.

Code snippet:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html class=" no-bgpositionxy" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
        <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
           <title>sample</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css"    media="screen" />
    <script src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Fav.ico">
   <meta name="robots" content="follow,index">



    <link type="text/css" href="css/BodyAlign.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">



     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Menu.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Menu1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/MenuDrop.js" language="javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            ct = "us";
            selURL = "manufacturing.html";
            $(function(){$('#popularSearches,#country-list').hide();});
        </script>


    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
     <!--
      .enlarge {width:330px;bottom:55px;}

      --> 
     </style>


  </head>

 <!-- Head -->

  <body>
```

below the code is menu so i want to make separate page for below code

```
<header id="header"> <div class="container">   <div id="topnav_wrap"> <ul id="topnav"> <li class="topnav_column_title"> <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

  <li id="why_workday_menu"> <a href="manufacturing.html">Why </a> <div style="width: 200px;" class="topnav_content 1-columns"> <ul class="topnav_column1 last">

<li class="topnav_column_title"> <a href="manufacturing.html">Why </a></li> <li> <a href="manufacturing.html">Designed for the Way You Work</a></li> <li> <a href="manufacturing.html">Real Cloud</a></li> <li> <a href="manufacturing.html">Mobile</a></li> <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`<object>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.3) in a non standard way like this:

```
<object name="header" type="text/html" data="header.inc.html"></object>
```

Or you can also use [SSI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html) if your server support it..

```
<!--#include file="header.inc.shtml" -->
```

If your html document can be parsed with php, you can use the [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statement..

```
<?php include('header.inc.phtml'); ?>
```

Another way is to use Ajax, e.g. with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/):

```
// if you have a container for it with id 'header-wrapper'
$('#header-wrapper').load('header.inc.html');

// ..or if you have no container for it
$.get("header.inc.html", function(data) {
    $("body").prepend(data);
});
```

Last but not least you can use a Frameset or a iFrame as bad practice.

Comment: Mamuz thanks for your valuable comments I have modified but its not work again please check below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941180/insert-page-not-work-in-html

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged the question with PHP, I'm going to assume you're using PHP for your server-side logic.  In that case, PHP has [an `include` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) which will include the contents of another PHP file at the location at which it's called.  That other file doesn't need to have PHP code, it can just be plain HTML.

So your code might look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php include "header.html"; ?>

        <!-- page-specific content goes here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

That way you just create the header content once in the `header.html` file and include it in every file where you want to use it.

Comment: I have tried like this but menu page not show can you share your mail id we will discus throw mail.

Comment: I have modified but its not work again please check below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941180/insert-page-not-work-in-html

Comment: @CheckMate: Is your PHP server working?  Is the file with the PHP code in it a PHP file or just an HTML file?

Answer (score 1):

Ok...where to begin...I'll show you how to create basic HTML5 master template.

If you don't have prefered text editor yet I would recommend [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.4.5.html)

1st - Create Master Page | `master.php`.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>

  <title>My Title</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="My Website">
  <meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3...">
  <meta name="author" content="Me">

  <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">

  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

</head>

<body>

  <header>

    <?php include('header.html'); ?>       <!-- Put Navigation in Header -->
    <?php include('navigation.html'); ?>   <!-- Or Make Separate Navigation -->

  </header>


  <div id="content">

    <?php include($page_content); ?>       <!-- More about this in final step -->
    <?php include('sidebar.html'); ?>      <!-- Yes, you can add the sidebar too :) -->
    <div class="clearfix"></div>           <!-- Smart to put it here ;) -->

  </div>


  <footer>

    <?php include('footer.html'); ?>

  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

---

*Note - In documents below we don't write `<!doctype html>` or anything else from the master page `master.php`.

---

2nd - Create `header.html` or `header.php` document.

```
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="Site Name"/>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

...and some more header content if needed...
```

---

3rd - Create `footer.html` or `footer.php` document.

```
<div>

  Some footer content here...

</div>

Anything else what we want in the footer area.
```

---

4th & Final - Create folder `includes` in your document root and in that folder create `.html` or `.php` document `index-content.php` with following content for example

```
<div id="divName">

   <p>this is some text...</p>

</div> 

and whatever you want here...
```

Than put newly created `index-content.php` in folder `includes`

Than create new document `index.php` and put it in document root folder

Content of the `index.php` document

```
<?php
  $page_content = 'includes/index-content.php';
  include('master.php');
?>
```

Now navigate in your web browser to `localhost/sitename/index.php` and done. 
 (if you do not have a localhost server up and running then open `index.php` in your web browser.

The same way later you create other pages/documents, for document content create e.g. 
`pagename-content.php` or `pagename-content.html` and for actual page which you link in navigation create pagename.php like in example above, than in navigation link call it like 
 `<a href="pagename.php">Page Name</a>`

---

That's it for now, for any additions please ask in comments.

Comment: To be first to comment on my post...I didn't sleep about 20 hours, if I forgot to include something or misspelled something or anything please fell free to mention that in comments.

Comment: mdesdev  thanks for your valuable comments I have modified but its not work again please check below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941180/insert-page-not-work-in-html

Comment: I edited my answer, I'm using this system for years now and I dont know how could I miss the index.php in my 1st version of answer(too tired perhaps), but now, everything is ok ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use SSI (Server side includes) if it enabled on your server.

`<!--#include file="menu.html" -->` or `<!--#include virtual="menu.html" -->`

Or use php include functions if php anabled on your server.

`<?php include 'menu.php'; ?>`

Comment: @Brid thanks for your valuable comments I have modified but its not work again please check below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941180/insert-page-not-work-in-html