# Adding a large amount of html and php content as PHP variable

Tags: php, html, css, include

I am trying to make my life a lot easier and make all pages have the same footer and head content from one file and this is what I have so far:

**Page with content**

```
<?php
include ("content.php");

echo $page_header;

?>

<div id="content">
</div>

<?php

echo $page_footer;

?>
```

**content.php**

```
<?php

    // This is the header which we want to have on all pages
    $page_header = include ("resources/content/header.php");

    // This is the footer which we want on all pages
    $page_footer = include ("resources/content/footer.php");

?>
```

**Header.php Example**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is my title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="logo">
        </div>
```

**Footer.php Example**

```
        <div id="footer">Copyright to me!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem I am having is my header.php content isn't all displaying and causing issues with the page formatting. The header.php does include some php `if` statements and some in-line javascript... should this matter?

Is there a better way of doing it?

***PLEASE NOTE: I am using PHP 5 locally and my server is PHP 4 so the answer needs to work for both***

Comment: `include ("resources/content/footer.php");` Instead of assigning it to a variable

Comment: There's nothing really wrong with that technique really, have you tried validating your HTML? there isn't any reason some conditional php or inline JS should make a difference, can you post the header.php content

Comment: I write about that in similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937026/insert-page-in-html-design/18937678#18937678).

Comment: @mdesdev not even relevant to my question.

Comment: Ok, but from what I see you're trying to create master page, same header, footer e.t.c. with changeable content and my solution is in same category except you are trying different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use output buffering functions for that.

Change **content.php** file:

```
ob_start();
include ("resources/content/header.php");
$page_header = ob_get_clean();

ob_start();
include ("resources/content/footer.php");
$page_footer = ob_get_clean();
```

[`ob_start()`](http://php.net/ob-start) function creates a temporary buffer for any output, then `include()` makes it's output not to page response, but to buffer that have been created by `ob_start()`. [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/ob-get-clean) collects contents of a buffer, destroys it and returns collected data as a string.

---

Another way as mentioned by **@u_mulder** is to simply `include()` those files right where they are needed.

Change **page with content** file:

```
<?php include ("resources/content/header.php"); ?>

<div id="content">
</div>

<?php include ("resources/content/footer.php"); ?>
```

However in some time you'll might need some complex template processing engine. There are plenty of them for php.

Comment: This worked a treat! Please could you go into more detail as to the benefits of using `ob_start();` over `include();`?

Comment: @AaronHatton note an update. There are no benefits. It's just preventing direct output and allows to collect and preprocess it, before give as the response to client browser.