# How to use option from a drop down list many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

i wonder if there's a way to use option from select tag for many drop down list. My html looks like :

```
<div id="backGround0"></div>
                        <div id="dropspot0"></div>
                        <p class="ziua0">LUNI<br/>
<select id="zile0">
                            <option value="01">01</option>
                            <option value="02">02</option>
                            <option value="03">03</option>
                            <option value="04">04</option>
                            <option value="05">05</option>
                            <option value="06">06</option>
                            <option value="07">07</option>
                            <option value="08">08</option>
                            <option value="09">09</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="11">11</option>
                            <option value="12">12</option>
                            <option value="13">13</option>
                            <option value="14">14</option>
                            <option value="15">15</option>
                            <option value="16">16</option>
                            <option value="17">17</option>
                            <option value="18">18</option>
                            <option value="19">19</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="21">21</option>
                            <option value="22">22</option>
                            <option value="23">23</option>
                            <option value="24">24</option>
                            <option value="25">25</option>
                            <option value="26">26</option>
                            <option value="27">27</option>
                            <option value="28">28</option>
                            <option value="29">29</option>
                            <option value="30">30</option>
                            <option value="31">31</option>
                        </select>
                        <select id="luniAn0">
                            <option value="Ianuarie">Ianuarie</option>
                            <option value="Februarie">Februarie</option>
                            <option value="Martie">Martie</option>
                            <option value="Aprilie">Aprilie</option>
                            <option value="Mai">Mai</option>
                            <option value="Iunie">Iunie</option>
                            <option value="Iulie">Iulie</option>
                            <option value="August">August</option>
                            <option value="Septembrie">Septembrie</option>
                            <option value="Octombrie">Octombrie</option>
                            <option value="Noiembrie">Noiembrie</option>
                            <option value="Decembrie">Decembrie</option>
                        </select>
                            </p>
```

And i want to add exactly the same values from above into these select tags:

```
                            <div id="backGround1"></div>
                        <div id="dropspot1"></div>
                        <p class="ziua1">MARTI<br/>
                            <select id="zile1">
                        </select>
                        <select id="luniAn1">
                        </select>
                            </p>
```

I have tried like this:

```
function dropDownLists(){
        var zileOptions = $.map($('#zile0 option'), function(e) { return e.value; });
        var luniAnOptions = $.map($('#luniAn option'), function(e) { return e.value; });


    for(var i = 1; i < 7; i++){
        zileToAdd = document.getElementById("zile" + i);
        luniToAdd = document.getElementById("luniAn" + i);

        zileToAdd.append("<option>" + zileOptions + "</option>");
        luniToAdd .append("<option>" + luniAnOptions + "</option>");
    }
}
```

Where i tried to take value of first select tag and add in another. But,i couldnt get option value,name or something else for Months...and neither

```
zileToAdd.append("<option>" + zileOptions + "</option>");
```

doesnt work :( That for shall add these two drop down lists 6 more times for select tags like id="zile" + i (for days) and id="luniAn" + i for second drop down list (months).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `html()` function

```
 $('#zile1').html($('#zile0').html());
 $('#luniAn1').html($('#luniAn0').html());
```

Please check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fshh9/)

Answer (score 2):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8LcVv/

```
var zile0 = $('#zile0').html();
$('#zile1').html(zile0);

var luniAn0 = $('#luniAn0').html();
$('#luniAn1').html(luniAn0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use html-defining javascript-variables:

```
var options = '<option value="01">01</option>' + 
               '<option value="02">02</option>' + 
               '<option value="03">03</option>';

$('#zile1').append(options);
$('#luniAn1').append(options);
```

something like this should work also.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the select block in one file; And include them where ever needed. This link may help you.

[Include same header and footer in multiple html files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309480/include-same-header-and-footer-in-multiple-html-files)

The benefit of using this technique is it allows you add same code in different pages.