# AngularJS ng-view not showing view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-routing

I'm developing a web app with AngularJS for the frontend and i'm trying to set the routing and showing the views, so far even ng-include and other stuff work for me but not ng-view
I'm developing in visual studio and when i run the app it's using a local server (localhost)

here's my directory structure

```
- ASP.NET project
---- Css
---- Scripts
-------- App
-------- app.js
----------- Home
-------------- Controllers
------------------ index-controller.js
---- Views
------- Partials
---------- navbar.html
------- home.html
- index.html
```

Here's mi index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Scolaris</title>
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Content/materialize/css/materialize.css" media="screen,projection" />

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body ng-app="app_module">

    <ng-include src="'Views/Partials/navbar.html'"/>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Content/materialize/js/materialize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/App/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/App/Home/Controllers/index-controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/initialization.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my app.js

```js
'use strict';
var app_module = angular.module('app_module', ['ngRoute']);
app_module.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
          templateUrl: '/Views/home.html',
          controller: 'indexController'
      })
      .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
      });
}]);
/* tried with ../../Views/home.html, ../Views/home.html, etc and nothing */
```

When i load the site it loads correctly and if i see the requests i can clearly see that it's requesting the home.html with 304 status code, the thing is the div with ng-view is not showing the html inside home.html, what could this be due to?

Comment: Any errors in console? Try removing `ng-include` and check if `ng-view loads`.

Comment: @Sourabh-  Tried removing the ng-include and ng-view loaded, why is that and how could i make it so the two work together?

Comment: Are `index.html` and `Views` folder are in same directory?

Comment: @HardCodeStuds This is a common problem, I am also not sure but I guess your `ng-view` instantiation is delayed due to `ng-include`. I guess you should switch to [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which is intented to deal with nested views.

Comment: @Sourabh- you are wrong..there is no such  thing in angularjs..basically ng-include div is not closed.so browser is wrapping that `ng-view ` div inside controller..& after loading of `ng-include` template `ng-view` div is getting replaced, look at my answer

Comment: <html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by changing the `<ng-include>` tag with an <`div ng-include="srctoview">` tag. If anyone is having this issue i'd recommend doing this, or doing it like in this answer [using a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23438974/2442274)

Thanks to @Sourabh- for leading me to an answer.

Comment: did you looked at my answer ever?

Answer (score 0):

close `<ng-include>` directive properly as browser is wrapping ur `<ng-view>` inside of `<ng-include>`. it will solve the problem. as @pankaj has already suggested.